# How do you sum one field by another field in an array of objects after grouping with dateTrunc?

Tags: mongodb, time-series, aggregation-framework

I'm using a time series collection in mongodb. The collection stores error counts for various APIs with the granularity of 1 minute. The API names are unknown and can change, so ideally you would not use a query that relies on static API names. Here's an example dataset:

```js
[
  {
    _time: ISODate("2022-03-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
    errors: [
      {
        api: "shipping",
        count: 10
      },
      {
        api: "inventory",
        count: 100
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _time: ISODate("2022-03-22T00:01:00.000Z"),
    errors: [
      {
        api: "shipping",
        count: 20
      },
      {
        api: "inventory",
        count: 200
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _time: ISODate("2022-03-22T00:02:00.000Z"),
    errors: [
      {
        api: "inventory",
        count: 300
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _time: ISODate("2022-03-22T00:03:00.000Z"),
    errors: [
      {
        api: "inventory",
        count: 400
      },
      {
        api: "account",
        count: 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm able to group into the correct time buckets using

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$_time",
          unit: "minute",
          binSize: 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I want to be able to:

1. Group documents into time buckets (dateTrunc).
2. Sum the error counts in each time bucket.

The result should be:

```
[
  {
    _time: ISODate("2022-03-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
    errors: [
      {
        api: "shipping",
        count: 30
      },
      {
        api: "inventory",
        count: 300
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _time: ISODate("2022-03-22T00:02:00.000Z"),
    errors: [
      {
        api: "inventory",
        count: 700
      },
      {
        api: "account",
        count: 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Or something like this could work too:

```
[
  {
    _time: ISODate("2022-03-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
    shipping: 30,
    inventory: 300
  },
  {
    _time: ISODate("2022-03-22T00:02:00.000Z"),
    inventory: 700,
    account: 1 
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right direction.

**Output 1**

1. `$set` - Add `truncTime` field.
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `errors` array into multiple documents.
3. `$group` - Group by `truncTime` and `errors.api`. And perform sum for `errors.count`.
4. `$group` - Group by `_id.truncTime`.
5. `$project` - Decorate the output document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      truncTime: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$_time",
          unit: "minute",
          binSize: 2
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$errors"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _time: "$truncTime",
        api: "$errors.api"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: "$errors.count"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._time",
      errors: {
        $push: {
          api: "$_id.api",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      _time: "$_id",
      errors: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Output 1)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9kzLmb_VqAq)

---

**Output 2**

1. `$set` - Same as above stage 1.
2. `$unwind` - Same as above stage 2.
3. `$group` - Same as above stage 3.
4. `$group` - Same as above step 4. Modify the fields in the `errors` array as `k` and `v`.
5. `$replaceRoot` - Replace input document to new document. Merge each document with key-value pair of `errors` array.
6. `$unset` - Remove `_id` and `errors` fields.

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._time",
      errors: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.api",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            _time: "$_id"
          },
          {
            $arrayToObject: "$errors"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "_id",
      "errors"
    ]
  }
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Output 2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BRByiydRmAg)